# Non-WiFi Wireless Connection between iOS and PC

Tags: .net, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

**Scenario**

There is an iPhone app I have written which needs to communicate with and transfer images to a .NET application running on Windows 7. Under normal circumstances it would communicate using WCF but there are times when LAN, Internet, TCP/IP stack are not availabe to the .NET application. In that case can the iOS app communicate with the .NET application wirelessly?

**Bluetooth**

One option I have been looking into is Bluetooth. The problem is that unless you go through MFi program, iOS only allows Bluetooth connection to devices which support something called *Bluetooth Low Energy* (BTLE) profile. Being a Bletooth newbie I'm not sure what BTLE really implies in terms of functionality supported. More importantly, is BTLE supported on most Bluetooth laptops? And can files be transferred over BTLE?

Any pointers regarding alternative wireless communication or the BTLE queries will be very helpful.

TIA

Comment: I don't think that bluetooth is limited to BTLE.  BTLE is very new to iPhone.  Older earpieces connect just fine an they are not BTLE.

Comment: The iPhone SDK support for Bluetooth is limited to BTLE. For non-BTLE you have to get MFi authorisation.